# DriveApp conversion from DocX to PDF fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to convert an existing .DOCX file on my Google Drive.
It works up until the new (PDF) file should be created, then I get this error message:
 "*Conversion from application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document to application/pdf failed*".

The relevant DOCX file should not be corrupted as it can be opened by Google Document and manually convertred to PDF from there.

I have enabled Drive API (both in Drive and in API Console)

Anyone else seen this problem?

Code:

```
 function convertPDF(fileid) {
     var docId = fileid;
     var f=DriveApp.getFileById(docId);
     var n=f.getName();
     var docFolder = f.getParents().next().getId();

     var docblob = f.getAs('application/pdf');
     n=n.replace(".docx",".pdf");
     docblob.setName(n);
     var bn=docblob.getName();
     var t=docblob.getContentType();
     Logger.log(bn+"-->"+t);  // <-- works 

     var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob); // <<- error msg here

     var fileId = file.getId();
     moveFileId(fileId, docFolder);
     return (fileId);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At Google, it cannot be directly converted from `docx` to `pdf`. But, after it converted `docx` to Google document, it can convert to `pdf`. In order to convert `docx` to Google document, you can use Drive API using Advanced Google services. For this, please enabling Drive API of Advanced Google services as follows.

1. In the script editor, select Resources > Advanced Google services
2. In the dialog that appears, click the on/off switch for Drive API v2.
3. Click OK button.

The detail information of Advanced Google services is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced).

I think that enabling Drive API at API console has already been done, because you have already used `DriveApp` on your script. Google automatically enables Drive API on API console when `DriveApp` is used in the script.

The modified script using Drive API is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function convertPDF(docx_id) {
  var docx = DriveApp.getFileById(docx_id);
  var docFolder = docx.getParents().next().getId();
  var n = docx.getName();
  var res = Drive.Files.insert({ // Here, Drive API of Advanced Google services is used.
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
    "title": n
  }, docx.getBlob());
  var f = DriveApp.getFileById(res.id).getBlob();

  var docblob = f.getAs('application/pdf');
  n=n.replace(".docx",".pdf");
  docblob.setName(n);
  var bn=docblob.getName();
  var t=docblob.getContentType();
  Logger.log(bn+"-->"+t);
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);
  var fileId = file.getId();
  Logger.log(fileId)
  moveFileId(fileId, docFolder);
  return (fileId);
}
```

I don't know about `moveFileId()`. So if an error occurs at this line, please check the function.

#### Note :

In this case, Google document is created as a temporally file for converting to PDF. The filename is the same to the docx file. So if it is not required for you, please delete it.

Comment: Thanks!
This works good enough, although the conversion to Google Doc has some negative side effects (a more complex layout may be altered)