# Google Apps script convert .docx file to .pdf

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am making a Google Apps Script 'Docs' add-in.

I have the following code:

```
  return {
      name: DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs('application/pdf').getName(),
      base64: Utilities.base64Encode(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs('application/pdf').getBytes())
    }
```

The `getActiveDocument()` method is forbidden returning this:
`Exception: The document is inaccessible. Please try again later. [line: 130, function: getPDF, file: Code]`
This is because google docs works with google doc files and not .docx files.

How could I convert the .docx file I have in Docs to a .pdf file?

Note: copying the file and deleting the previous one is not an option.

Note: I want to do it within the app (in the code). Not manually :)

Comment: If you want to convert DOCX format to PDF format, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46252645 But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Okay, this copies the current file that I want to convert, plus I cannot get the current file's Id.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Okay, this copies the current file that I want to convert, plus I cannot get the current file's Id.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Yes, no problem your English is great.  
1. I want to use the same file, not create a new one. In the answer of the question you posted: it contains this:  var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob); which is creating new file, a copy of the previous file. I would not like to create new files.
2. I don't have the file's id to get its content because this method ``getActiveDocument()`` does not work for .docx files.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that you wanted to convert from DOCX data to PDF data. Is my understanding correct? In the script of `var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);` in [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46259348), a PDF file is created. In your situation, you want to overwrite the DOCX file with the created PDF file. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score -1):

Open your docx document in MS Word 2013.
2Click on the File tab and select Save as.
3Choose the folder where you want to save the file. In the drop-down menu Save as type, choose PDF. Click the Save button and your docx file will be saved in PDF.

Comment: No I want to do it within the app (in the code). Not manually :)

Comment: You answer is totally out of scope. The question is asking for a in-app solution. Please, read carefully the questions otherwise you risk diverting the understanding of those who will read in the future.